# When should I use a render function?

Tags: vue.js

By the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) I do not fully understand when I should use `render: h => h(App)` function.

For example I have very simple Vue app:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App }
})
```

What is the case when I need add to code: `render: h => h(App)`?

Comment: You can use render functions to produce the same output as a standard vue but you have more flexibilty with render functions because you have more control and can do things programmatically that you are not able to with standard vue

Comment: See also this article: https://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2017/05/the-meaning-of-vuejs-render-h-happ.html

Comment: Late comer, if people still looking an answer to this - [What does the ‘h’ stand for in Vue’s render method?](https://css-tricks.com/what-does-the-h-stand-for-in-vues-render-method/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the example you posted, `App.vue` represents the main app wrapper - all related `.vue` component files would be imported there.

So in your `Vue` instance you defined the components object, and added the App component, but how would you exactly mount that component to the instance and display it?

A couple of things to keep in mind:

- This is not a `.vue` file, so you don't have a template tag option. This is a pure `.js` file
- You can't put `<App></App>` into the `template` property because you are using runtime only build so the template option is not available

One option is using render functions. It's what `Vue.js` does under the hood. It takes your template and then template compiler converts it to render functions.

Alternatively, instead of a render function, you can the use spread operator:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    ...App
})
```

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html):

> Vue recommends using templates to build your HTML in the vast majority
> of cases. There are situations however, where you really need the full
> programmatic power of JavaScript. That’s where you can use the render
> function

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>'
})
```